# Cisco catalyst 45xx series compatibility with RG45 10Gb

Tags: cisco, switch, 10gbase, cisco-4500, line-card

I'm looking for a compatible RG45 10Gb line card with Cisco catalyst WS-C4507R+E/WS-X45-SUP7-E
Unfortunately I was unable to find any useful information in data sheets.
Can anyone help me? I'm really confused.
If possible please leave a valid link.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know that with the `WS-C4507R+E` supervisor, you can use the `WS-X4712-SFP+E Catalyst 4500 E-Series 12-Port 10GbE (SFP+)` line card. The SFP+ slots can use either 1 Gb SFP or 10 Gb SFP+ transceivers.

There is a caveat: the ASICs on the line card each control three ports, and the ASICs can only handle 12 Gb each. This gives you four ASICs per the 12 ports on the line card, and that will give you the full slot bandwidth. You could use one 10 Gb and two 1 Gb ports for each of the three ports per ASIC for a full line rate. If you use three 10 Gb ports on the ASIC, you will drop some traffic if the traffic on the ASIC exceeds 12 Gb.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance at [this data sheet](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/catalyst-4500-series-line-cards/product_data_sheet0900aecd802109ea.html), table 1 seem to indicate that your chassis and SUP support all line cards except the 24Gbps 47xx series.
So I may have missed one or two but it seems all these are supported:

```
WS-X4148-RJ
WS-X4248-RJ45V
WS-X4506-GB-T
WS-X4548-GB-RJ45
WS-X4548-GB-RJ45V
WS-X4548-RJ45V+
WS-X4748-RJ45-E
WS-X4748-RJ45V+E
```

In addition there are line cards with SFP ports that can be used with RJ45 SFPs, from the WS-X4448-GB-SFP up to the WS-X4748-SFP-E.

Having said all that, I strongly advise you to double check with your Cisco Partner/Reseller before ordering. Or in case you are considering buying from another source, make sure to get a money-back guarantee as there are sometimes corner case scenarios (like card X is supported but requires IOS version Y, and you already have another line card Z that is no longer supported in version Y).